# Apache : Restrict acces to webserver via IP (HTTP/HTTPS)

Tags: apache, ip, lets-encrypt, restriction

I run a website on a VPS and I would like to completely block access to the website via The VPS IP Address.
I made it work for HTTP but It seems impossible for HTTPS.
What I did:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Redirect 403 /
DocumentRoot /a/folder/here/
</VirtualHost>
```

This worked perfectly as expected for http://xx.xx.xx.xx

**But** I could not find a way to do the same for https://xx.xx.xx.xx

Anyone can help me please?

** I am using:**

Letsencrypt Certificat

Apache 2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the same for the virtual host that is bonded to port 443:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        Redirect 403 /
        DocumentRoot /a/folder/here/
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I didn't think of IfModule
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: the file containing this rule must be executed after other sites that use SSL.

ecample:

**0-site1.conf** = website using no ssl (port 80)

**0-site1-ssl.conf** = website using ssl (port 443)

**1-direct-access-conf** = the file containing:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Redirect 403 /
    DocumentRoot /a/folder/here/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```